# XPath for selecting all siblings until a div

Tags: python, html, xpath

I have the following HTML structure. Each `<div>` represents a state and each `<a>` tag represents a city within that state

```
<div class="country">AL</div>
<a href=somelink>City1</a>
<a href=somelink>City2</a>
<a href=somelink>City3</a>
<a href=somelink>City4</a>
<a href=somelink>City5</a>
<div class="country">CA</div>
<a href=somelink>City21</a>
<a href=somelink>City22</a>
<a href=somelink>City23</a>
<a href=somelink>City24</a>
<div class="country">IL</div>
<a href=somelink>City31</a>
<a href=somelink>City32</a>
<a href=somelink>City33</a>
<a href=somelink>City34</a>
```

I need to extract all a tags that belong to a certain state.
I tried this:

```
//*[contains(text(), "CA")]/following-sibling::a[preceding::div]
```

But it got me

> City21 City22 City23 City24 City31 City32 City33 City34

while I only wanted

> City21 City22 City23 City24

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try below `XPAth` expression:

```
//a[count(following-sibling::div)=count(//div[text()="AL"]/following-sibling::div)-1]
```

or

```
//a[preceding-sibling::div[2][text()="AL"]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can select tags `a` such that the first `div` before contains the state abbreviation:

```
//a[preceding::div[1][contains(text(), "CA")]]
```